# Incorrect mapping: Google admob mediation

Tags: android, admob

Google Admob mediation is showing INCORRECT MAPPING and No requests. I'm attaching screenshots for your reference. Can anyone help?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: same issue with admob to Facebook ads mediation

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens in AdMob side and they are not doing anything I also contact another ad source they say its the problem from the admob side